# WPF Button effects

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need a button that changes color when clicked once and then reverts to the original color when clicked again (this cycle keeps going)
I am new to wpf and don't really know where to start.
Please could someone give me some pointers

Edit
Following the advise of Tayyab I am now on the way

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you considered using [ToggleButton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton?view=netframework-4.8) instead?

Comment: So you need something which can hold the state and then something which changes the color of the button based on the state. If you are not using the Model-View-ViewModel pattern, you should probably look at the code behind the view. But it would be nice with something to work from, so maybe try adding some sort of code you tried...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple way would be simply to maintain state (you can use MVVM if you wish) of the current color and to toggle it on every button click. Following is the code which does what you desire:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="93" Margin="66,60,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="208" Click="button_Click" Background="Red"/>

</Grid>

</Window>
```

And handling the click event like:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private static string toggle = "blue";//State of button's color
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Switch to decide and toggle the required color
            switch (toggle)
            {
                case "blue":
                    button.Background = Brushes.Blue;
                    toggle = "red";
                    break;
                case "red":
                    button.Background = Brushes.Red;
                    toggle = "blue";
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
```

Hope this will provide the basis for what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

If you need only 2 states, then use toggle button. Custom ControlTemplate is not required, but it will help to make it look neat.

```
<ToggleButton Width="100" Height="30" Content="Click me!">
    <ToggleButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="5">
                            <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                              Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                              />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ToggleButton.Style>
</ToggleButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you , so the color of button is red when you click it the color will be black and when it is black it will be red 
this is the xaml code :

```
<Button Content="Change color" Name="btn" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="Red" Margin="181,131,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
```

and this is the code of Button_Click function :

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        btn.Background = btn.Background == Brushes.Red ? Brushes.Black : Brushes.Red;
    }
```